# OpenCV BackgroundSubtractor Thinks A Busy Foreground Is The Background

Tags: opencv

I am using background subtraction to identify and control items on a conveyor belt.
The work is very similar to the typical tracking cars on a highway example.
I start out with an empty conveyor belt so the computer knows the background in the beginning.
But after the conveyor has been full of packages for a while the computer starts to think that the packages are the background. This requires me to restart the program from time to time.
Does anyone have a workaround for this?
Since the conveyor belt is black I am wondering if it maybe makes sense to toss in a few blank frames from time to time or if perhaps there is some other solution.
Much Thanks

```py
# After experimentation, these values seem to work best.
backSub = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history = 5000, varThreshold = 1000, detectShadows = False)    

while True:
    return_value, frame = vid.read()
    
    if frame is None:
        print('Video has ended or failed, try a different video format!')
        break        
    
        
    ## [gaussian blur helps to remove noise These settings seem to remove reflections from rollers.] 
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (0,0), 5, 0, 0)
    ## [End of: gaussian blur helps to remove noise These settings seem to remove reflections from rollers.]
    

    ## [Remove the background and produce a grays scale image]
    fgMask = backSub.apply(blur)       
    ## [End of: Remove the background and produce a grey scale image]
```

Comment: you ask for alternate solutions. that's good, but we're gonna need to see some data/pictures/video. -- yes, those background subtractors will adapt to what they've seen recently. depending on algorithm, parameters like history depth or learning rate would need adjusting, i.e. set to "no learning" after background has been learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you're giving the background subtractor some pure background initially.

When you're done with that and in the "running" phase, call `apply()` specifically with `learningRate = 0`. That ensures the model won't be updated.

Comment: That was it! It's been running all day. Much thanks.